# PWA - multiple manifest files

Tags: html, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I have a PWA SPA app. I want the orientation on mobile phones to be blocked on portrait mode (`"orientation": "portrait"`). On tablets and computers, I want to not have a certain orientation (`"orientation": "any"`).
In this sense I think I should use two manifest files. Files to be used according to the device on which the application is used.
My approach is to use the `media` attribute for the `link` tag.

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.big.json" media="all and (orientation: landscape)">
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" media="all and (orientation: portrait)">
```

So, the first manifest should be used on devices with landscape orientation and the second should be used only for phones and something like this.
In the first manifest I can use `"orientation": "any"` and in the second I can use `"orientation": "portrait"` to reach my goal. This trick can be used also to have declared in each manifest proper screenshots - suitable for the type of device used (phones / tablets&computers).

The only problem is that this approach is not working. The browsers do not respect the attribute `media` and honor the first manifest appeared in the document, regardless of what is specified in the `media` attribute.

How can I achieve what I said above and have two types of orientation depending on the type of device running the application?

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in method to load different manifest files based on the device's orientation or type in the Web App Manifest specification. This is why your approach with the media attribute isn't working. The browser will always select the first linked manifest file, regardless of media attributes.

If you're aiming to handle different orientations, you would typically need to utilize JavaScript at runtime, specifically the Screen Orientation API, to lock the screen orientation. I'd recommend to just make your application responsive and adjust to different screen sizes. You would use media queries for that, here is some resources:

[Media query spec](https://web.dev/learn/design/media-queries/)
[Complete Guide](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-css-media-queries/)

An alternative workaround, if this is required, could involve serving different manifest files from your server, based on the user agent. This way, you might be able to serve a 'portrait' manifest file for mobile browsers and a 'landscape' one for desktop browsers. But keep in mind, this isn't a reliable solution as user agent strings can often be unreliable and they won't provide information about the actual orientation of the device.